# Floating table class css

Tags: html, css

The table is floated to right and the width is decreased to the size of left part of paragraphs but it is shown in the bottom of paragraphs.
The same coding form works with images, but not with paragraphs and tables.
What should I do?

My html:

```
<p>random paragraph</p>
    <table class="sagi1" border="10px">
        <th>Random</th>
        <th>Random</th>   
    </tr>
```

And my css:

```
.name {
    float:right;   
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Post a complete code example in your question please.

Comment: Please edit the question with your code, don't post it as a comment.

Comment: Most likely, with the viewport (the width of the browser window) you are using, is simply too small to fit that wide table next to the paragraph. So as a result, it's breaking it down to the next line. EDIT: nevermind, the code I copied now looks different from your edited post

Comment: I tried to use paragraph with 2 words but it did not work , the normal width of table is around half width of html body, is there any other code i can do it maybe i wrote it wrong , it works with images but not with tables

Answer (score 1):

Put the table first in code, then the paragraph following it:

```
 <table class ="sagi1" border = "10px" style="float: right;"> <tr><th>Random</th> <th>Random</th> <th>Random</th> <th>Random</th> <th>Random</th> </tr> </table><p>Random.RandomRandomRandomRandomRandom Random Random Random Random Random Random Random Random Random Random Random Random Random Random Random Random</p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tuyhppap/

Comment: Same error , paragraph on the left side but table is on right and the bottom , width is fixed but it stays on the bottom